# Limit the bandwidth for microsoft windows updates with pfsense

Tags: pfsense-2

In our infrastructure we have no WSUS installed so when microsoft pushes new updates all our computers start excessive downloads, we use pfsense and as I am new to it, I need an advise how can I limit the download bandwidth from the certain hosts having only hostnames of the update servers from here
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708605(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Limiting incoming traffic can be a problem, since by the time you see the traffic, it has already used your bandwidth. You could drop it after it reaches your network, but that doesn't unclog the WAN pipe.

Comment: Actually I have two pfsense routers and ingress traffic on one interface is egress traffic for another interface, can't I limit it there?

Comment: You can limit it anywhere you see the traffic, but my point is that it has already clogged your inbound WAN by the time you see it.

Comment: TCP's flow control can adjust the windows size from the client size, isn't it?

Comment: Anyways I can try if you can "show" me how to do that in pfsens having only hostnames

Comment: That will not be very accurate. You couldn't give it a specific amount of bandwidth. If something is using UDP (TFTP, video streams, etc.) you would affect it at all.

Comment: TCP will quickly adjust to the ammount of bandwidth it is given. If it didn't networks would barely work at all.

Comment: @RonMaupin the WSUS service is HTTP/HTTPS (TCP based).  As Others here pointed out, you _can_ throttle incoming traffic down with firewall/Layer4 policies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the rest of your pfSense setup plays well with it, setting up your pfSense  so that squid can cache the updates really speeds things up, while limiting the WAN traffic. This may require more resources than many people seem to allocate to a pfSense install, and it spent quite a while being broken from 2.15 or so forward (I don't know if it's actually fixed for sure in the current release, it partly depends on what other things you are doing with pfSense, IIRC.)

Alternatively, set up a separate squid box, tuned to handle the rather portly things that are system updates, as opposed to the typical default tuning for smaller things that leaves updates out of the cache.

On the third hand, setting up a local WSUS might be the most sensible approach for your location, if it's ONLY windows updates that are the issue. Otherwise all those hosts **are** going to move all that traffic eventually, while having that set up will limit your WAN traffic to pulling down one copy.

Answer (score 1):

With traffic shaper you can limit bandwidth to destination IP's.

List of domains used by windows update, but you need to resolve those IP's yourself as they change time to time.

```
http://windowsupdate.microsoft.com
http://*.windowsupdate.microsoft.com
https://*.windowsupdate.microsoft.com
http://*.update.microsoft.com
https://*.update.microsoft.com
http://*.windowsupdate.com
http://download.windowsupdate.com
http://download.microsoft.com
http://*.download.windowsupdate.com
http://wustat.windows.com
http://ntservicepack.microsoft.com
http://stats.microsoft.com
https://stats.microsoft.com
```

There's a Microsoft page with the URLs:

"Configure WSUS - Connect to Microsoft domains on the internet"

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-server-update-services/deploy/2-configure-wsus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-server-update-services/deploy/2-configure-wsus#211-configure-your-firewall-to-allow-your-first-wsus-server-to-connect-to-microsoft-domains-on-the-internet)

Comment: suppose I have the ip addresses of this servers, how can I limit the traffic from them?

Comment: traffic shaper in pfsense.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EfXImr5q-sw

Comment: honestly, if it would work reliably or easy in pfSense, it would be included and easy to enable by default. which it ain't. or there would be many implementations that look similar, and current, authoritative howtos for this exact scenario that one can refer people to. which there aren't. it's good to point people at the features they might have success with, but it should be made clearer how well this all works, or what the implications are.